# matplotlib.patches.Arc() cannot update theta2 parameter in runtime

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I am using Python 2.7.10 with matplotlib 1.4.3

I am trying to draw a plot that contains an instance of

```
matplotlib.patches.Arc(xy, width, height, angle=0.0, theta1=0.0, theta2=360.0, **kwargs)
```

During run time I allow the user to change certain parameters which affects the plot. In this case I am trying to change the theta1 and theta2 parameters of an Arc instance that already exist.

However, the theta1 and theta2 parameters do not update. I am able to update the other parameters: center, width, height and angle, but not theta1 and theta2.

I instantiate an arc by

```
Arc1 = matplotlib.patches.Arc(....)
```

and then later in a subroutine, I change some parameters with

```
Arc1.center = new_center_position #Changes parameter
Arc1.width  = new_width           #Changes parameter
Arc1.height = new_height          #Changes parameter
Arc1.angle  = new_angle           #Changes parameter
Arc1.theta1 = new_start_angle     #Does not change parameter
Arc1.theta2 = new_end_angle       #Does not change parameter
fig.canvas.draw_idle()            #Redraw canvas to reflect changes
```

Secondly, is there some other way in which I can update a number of parameters at once without having to do each in a new line?

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would consider this to be a bug, and you may file an issue at matplotlib.

The problem is that the `Path` that contains the arc is not updated when setting `matplotlib.patches.Arc.theta1`. Since `matplotlib.patches.Arc` does not have any setter method, a workaround is to create a new `Path` each time via

```
matplotlib.patches.Arc._path = matplotlib.patches.Path.arc(theta1 , theta2)
```

Below is a complete example of how to use it.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider


fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(121, aspect="equal")

ax_x = plt.axes([0.58, 0.75, 0.33, 0.03], axisbg="w")
ax_y = plt.axes([0.58, 0.65, 0.33, 0.03], axisbg="w")
ax_w = plt.axes([0.58, 0.55, 0.33, 0.03], axisbg="w")
ax_h = plt.axes([0.58, 0.45, 0.33, 0.03], axisbg="w")
ax_a = plt.axes([0.58, 0.35, 0.33, 0.03], axisbg="w")
ax_t1 = plt.axes([0.58, 0.25, 0.33, 0.03], axisbg="w")
ax_t2 = plt.axes([0.58, 0.15, 0.33, 0.03], axisbg="w")

s_x = Slider(ax_x, 'x', -1, 1, valinit=0)
s_y = Slider(ax_y, 'y', -1, 1, valinit=0)
s_w = Slider(ax_w, 'width', 0, 2, valinit=0.5)
s_h = Slider(ax_h, 'height', 0, 2, valinit=0.5)
s_a = Slider(ax_a, 'angle', 0, 360, valinit=0)
s_t1 = Slider(ax_t1, 'theta1', 0, 360, valinit=0)
s_t2 = Slider(ax_t2, 'theta2', 0, 360, valinit=360)

arc = matplotlib.patches.Arc( (0,0), width=0.5, height=0.5, linewidth=4, color="#bd3270")
ax.add_patch(arc)

def update(val):
    arc.center = (s_x.val, s_y.val) 
    arc.width  = s_w.val         
    arc.height = s_h.val            
    arc.angle  = s_a.val             
    arc.theta1 = s_t1.val         
    arc.theta2 = s_t2.val
    ## this is the line to add
    arc._path = matplotlib.patches.Path.arc(s_t1.val , s_t2.val)    
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

for s in [s_x,s_y, s_w, s_h, s_a, s_t1, s_t2]:
    s.on_changed(update)

ax.set_xlim([-1,1])
ax.set_ylim([-1,1])
plt.show()
```

[image]